# Differentiating with respect to the lower bound of an integral with a PDF

Tags: integration, statistics, definite-integrals

I am trying to find $\frac{d}{dR}\int_{R}^{\bar{v}}(v-R)g(v)dv$, where $v$ is a random variable distributed on $[\underline{v}, \bar{v}]$, with pdf $g(v)$ and CDF $G(v)$. I found that:

\begin{array}{l}
=\frac{d}{d R} \int_{R}^{\bar{v}}(v-R) g(v) d v=\frac{d}{d R}[(v-R) G(v)]_{R}^{\bar{v}} \\
=\frac{d}{d R}[(\bar{v}-R) G(\bar{v})-(R-R) G(R)] \\
=\frac{d}{d R}[\bar{v}-R]=-1
\end{array}

Is this at all correct? Thank you.

Comment: On the top line of your sequence of equalities, how did you get from the first expression to the second one?

Comment: I took the integral of (v-R)g(v) with respect to v @JohnBarber

Comment: Did you? Better check. What happens if you take the derivative of $(v-R)G(v)$? Do you get back the integrand $(v-R)g(v)$?

Comment: @JohnBarber Indeed; I see my error. Thank you.